# How to extract axios http request from a component if it requires setState on local state(typescript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios

I am looking for a solution such that I can put `getFavList` function in `service.ts` file. However, since `setAllData` is involved. I cannot really wrap my mind on how to do this. Here is the original code.

index.tsx

```
export default function FavoriteList() {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState<Data[]>([])
  const [hasUpdated, setHasUpdated] = useState<Boolean>(true)

  const getFavList = async () => {
    await axios.get(`${API}/api/favCharityList`)
      .then((res => {
        let arr = []
        arr = [...res.data.charities]
        setAllData(arr)
      }))
      .catch(err => console.error(`Error: ${err}`))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getFavList();
  }, [hasUpdated])

  return (
    <></>
  )
}
```

I tried to put it in a separate file. However, the `setAllData` line return an error.
Error message

> ```
> Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<[]>'.
>   Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: []) => []'.
>     Type 'any[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: []): []'.
> ```

new index.tsx

```
export default function FavoriteList() {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState<Data[]>([])
  const [hasUpdated, setHasUpdated] = useState<Boolean>(true)

  const getFavList = async () => {
    await axios.get(`${API}/api/favCharityList`)
      .then((res => {
        let arr = []
        arr = [...res.data.charities]
        setAllData(arr)
      }))
      .catch(err => console.error(`Error: ${err}`))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getFavList({ API, setAllData });
  }, [hasUpdated])

  return (
    <></>
  )
}
```

service.ts

```js
interface AxiosArg {
  API: string
  setAllData: Dispatch<SetStateAction<[]>>
}

const getFavList = async ({ API, setAllData }: AxiosArg) => {
  await axios.get(`${API}/api/favCharityList`)
    .then((res => {
      let arr = []
      arr = [...res.data.charities]
      setAllData(arr)
    }))
    .catch(err => console.error(`Error: ${err}`))
}

export { getFavList }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of closing over a *specific* state updater function, refactor the `getFavList` function to simply ***return*** the fetched data and let the calling code handle what it needs to do with that data.

It's a general anti-pattern to mix `async/await` with Promise chains. Choose one or the other in most cases.

Example refactor:

```js
const getFavList = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${API}/api/favCharityList`);
    return data.charities as Data[];
  } catch {
    return [] as Data[];
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
import { getFavList } from '../service';

export default function FavoriteList() {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState<Data[]>([]);
  const [hasUpdated, setHasUpdated] = useState<Boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFavList().then((data) => {
      setAllData(data);
    });
  }, [hasUpdated]);

  return (
    <>....</>
  )
}
```